# Why in PHP, when handling to non-array variable like to array doesnt gives PHP-Notice

Tags: php, arrays

Why,

```
  $b = [];
  echo $b[0]; //gives E_NOTICE Undefined offset: 0
```

gives notice?

But,

```
$b = false;
echo $b[0]; // no notice or warnings

var_dump($b[0]) // returns NULL
```

Could this be due to php.ini settings?

Comment: I don't have a direct answer, but I can give you a tips on using `is_array($myVar);` to check if your variable is an array, and then checking if your column is set using `if (isset($b[0])) {}`.

Comment: Because of type inference. Using a variable as certain type makes the interpreter to try to cast it to this type and use it as one.